# WebSecurity Login only for the lifetime of the browser window

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, simplemembership

I am using SimpleMemberships in ASP.NET to handle users logging in and out, I was wondering if anyone knew how to set it so that their login session expires on browser close.

I set the persistCookie as false but it still keeps them logged in even after closing the browser.

EDIT:

```
        [HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model, string returnUrl)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid && WebSecurity.Login(model.UserName, model.Password, false))
            {
                return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
            }

            // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user name or password provided is incorrect.");
            return View(model);
        }
```

Comment: Are you closing all of the browser windows?

Answer (score 2):

If the cookie is not persistent as in your case, it is stored in the memory of the current browser instance and when you close it, the cookie will be lost. Make sure though that you have closed all browser windows and tabs if you had any.

Answer (score 1):

You can direct the page to the logout url when browser is going to closed, Try this JavaScript

```
window.onbeforeunload =function(){
 location.href = 'signOutUrl'; 
}
```

But the issue is you can't guarantee that the user will close the browser. May be he can disconnect the internet. And also since this client side JavaScript solution user can change this code easily.